# C++ Garbage at the end of file

Tags: c++

I have a problem and I dont know how to solve it.
The issue is:

```
char * ary = new Char[];

ifstream fle;
fle.open(1.txt, ios_base::binary);
fle.seekg(fle.end);
long count = fle.tellg();
fle.seek(fle.beg);
```

here is the problem:
File 1.txt contains: Hello world!.

when I execute:

```
ary = new char(count);
fle.read(ary, count);
```

the ary filled like this: Hello world! @T#^@$@FF(garbage)

The file is ookay nothing inside it only what is above.

Platform: Win 7, VS 2012

Any idea how to solve this issue. (Solved)

(Problem 2)
Now I am facing another problem, the fle.read sometimes read more than the size i gave. For Example if i passed like fle.read(buffer, 1000) it ends in some cases (strlen(buffer) =  1500. How can i solve this?

Regards,

Comment: it isnt in the file, that is part of your allocated memory. try nulling the array before you do anything. ie `ary = new char(count); memset(ary, 0, count); fle.read(ary,count);`, for memset, you will also need `#include <string.h>` if  you dont already have it.

Comment: Why are you opening the file in binary?

Comment: And count has an `o` in it.

Comment: @bizzehdee - `memset` requires `<string.h>` or `<cstring>`

Comment: `new char(..)` creates a single char not an array! and `new char[]` is pointless! (didn't even know it would compile).

Comment: @NeilKirk It won't.  And of course `new char[count]` still leaves open the question of where you do the delete (including if `fle.read` terminates with an exception).  The only reasonable solutions involve `std::vector<char>` or `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is not that your array contains garbage, but that you forgot to put the null-terminator character at the end and your print statement doesn't know when to stop.

Also, you wrote `new char(count)` instead of `new char[count]`. In the first case, you only instantiate one `char` with value `count` while in the second case you create a buffer of `count` characters.

Try this:

```
ary = new char[count+1];
fle.read(ary, count);
ary[count] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks That did what I want, for me instead of increasing the buffer I just made ary[count -1] = '\0' otherwise I will have to change the receiver buffer size, if am not wrong.

Comment: If you do `ary[count-1] = '\0'`, you will lose the last byte.

Comment: Yea, but I changed the read size to -1 so I can keep that byte empty.
Now I am facing another problem, the fle.read sometimes read more than the size i gave. For Example if i passed like fle.read(destination, 1000) it ends in some cases 1500. How can i solve this?

Comment: @JamesKanze Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, but... why use `new char[]`, when `std::vector<char>` is so much better.  (Consider what happens if `fle.read` throws an exception.)

Comment: It would be better to mention the allocation problem in the answer. If it's just fixed in the code this important point will easily be missed by the reader.

Answer (score 5):

char[]-strings in C are usually null-terminated. They are one byte longer than necessary, and the last byte is set to `0x00`. That's necessary because C has no way to tell the length of an array.

When you read binary data from a file, no terminating null-character is read into the string. That means a function like printf which operates on char-arrays of unknown length will output the array and any data which happens to come after it in memory until it encounters a null-character.

**Solution:** allocate the char[]-buffer one byte longer than the length of the data and set the last byte to `0` manually.

**Better solution:** Don't use C-style char-arrays. Do it the object-oriented way and use the class [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) to represent strings.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the other answers miss a very important point:
When you do `ary = new char(count);` you allocate A SINGLE CHARACTER initialized with a symbol with ASCII code `count`.
You should write this: `ary = new char[count + 1];`

Comment: Two nits (because you _do_ have the right answer, unlike all of the others): there's no ASCII involved here.  A `char` is just another type of small integer, and you initialize it with the integral value of `count` (converted to a `char`, of course).  And what he _should_ write is more along the lines of `std::vector<char> ary( count + 1);`.

Comment: @James Why no ASCII involved? When you write `char(32)` you will get a space inside because 32 is the ASCII code for the space, won't you?

Comment: What you get on output depends on the output device.  How you interpret it internally is up to you; if you interpret it as a character, and 32 is the code point for space in the encoding you're using (which is probably the case, even if ASCII itself is pretty much dead, and not used anywhere), then you will interpret it as a space.  But in the end, `char` is an integral data type, which holds integral values.  And in an expression like `new char(count)`, there's nothing to say that `count` should be interpreted as a code point, rather than an ordinary integral value.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the most obvious problem is that you are allocating using
`new char(count)`, which allocates a single `char`, initialized
with `count`.  What you were probably trying to do would be `new
char[count]`.  What you really need is:

```
std::vector<char> arr( count );
fle.read( &arr[0], count );
```

Or maybe `count + 1` in the allocation, if you want a trailing
`'\0'` in the buffer.

EDIT:

Since you're still having problems: `fle.read` will never read
more than requested.  What does `fle.gcount()` return after the
read?

If you do:

```
std::vector<char> arr( count );
fle.read( &arr[0], count );
arr.resize( fle.gcount() );
```

you should have a vector with exactly the number of `char` that
you have read.  If you want them as a string, you can construct
one from `arr.begin(), arr.end()`, or even use `std::string`
instead of `std::vector<char>` to begin with.

If you need a `'\0'` terminated string (for interface with
legacy software), then just create your vector with a size of
`count + 1`, instead of `count`, and `&arr[0]` will be your
`'\0'` string.

Do *not* try to use `new char[count]` here.  It's very difficult
to do so correctly.  (For example, it will require a try block
and a catch.)

Answer (score 1):

We have to guess a little here, but most likely this comes down to an issue with your debugging. The buffer is filled correctly, but you inspect its contents incorrectly.

Now, `ary` is declared as `char*` and I suspect that when you attempt to inspect the contents of `ary` you use some printing method that expects a null-terminated array. But you did not null-terminate the array. And so you have a buffer overrun.

If you had only printed `count` characters, then you would not have overrun. Nor would you if you had null-terminated the array, not forgetting to allocate an extra character for the null terminator.

Instead of using raw arrays and `new`, it would make much more sense to read the buffer into `std::string`. You should be trying to avoid null-terminated strings as much as possible. You use those when performing interop with non-C++ libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ary = new char[count + 1];
fle.read(ary,count);
ary[count] = '\0';
```

The terminating null character was missing - its not in the file, you have to add it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You're reading `count` characters for a file, you have to allocate one extra character to provide for the string terminator (`\0`).

```
ary = new char[count + 1];
ary[count] = '\0';
```

Comment: This still only allocates a single `char`.  (What he really needs, of course, is `std::vector<char> ary( count + 1 );`.)